# Podemos nos "cansar fácil", "esquecer fácil" ou até "desistir fácil"?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, sintaxe, advérbios, coloquialismos

Em Português, "fácil" é um adjetivo e "facilmente" um advérbio.  Até aí, nada de novo. Contudo, eu frequentemente ouço:

- "Eu estou me cansando muito fácil."
- "Tu esqueces fácil, mas eu não."
- "Você perde o controle muito fácil."

E também leio em livros e revistas:

> - [estamos diante de uma geração que às vezes desiste fácil de seus sonhos](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=AvS0CwAAQBAJ&pg=PT115&dq=%22desiste+f%C3%A1cil%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidr_Sw09HQAhXRnJAKHfruDaAQ6AEIITAB)
> - [A gente se cansa muito fácil. Se cansa de pensar. Se cansa de agir. Se cansa de tentar.](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=13&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjr_uvd0dHQAhWGjJAKHcNKAq4QFghOMAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftaniagorodniuk.blogspot.com%2F2014%2F01%2Fa-gente-nunca-se-cansa-de-amar.html&usg=AFQjCNGMDDQlrHl-3XhutmXv_kD9qbUIIw&bvm=bv.139782543,d.Y2I)
> - [Você se cansa muito fácil de suas conquistas.](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=H1G3DAAAQBAJ&pg=PT75&dq=%22se+cansa+muito+f%C3%A1cil%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf8KGq0dHQAhWFk5AKHe8kDmwQ6AEIGzAA)
> - [Você desiste fácil demais!](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=bvitBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT59&dq=%22desiste+f%C3%A1cil%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidr_Sw09HQAhXRnJAKHfruDaAQ6AEISTAI)
> - [...ela se cansa muito fácil nos passeios e sempre pede colo.](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=18&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjkpeSF0tHQAhVJlJAKHRkuBo84ChAWCD8wBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.euvoceeoscachorros.com%2F2015%2F08%2F14%2Fpor-que-investir-em-um-carrinho-de-transporte-para-pets%2F&usg=AFQjCNGiB0Qp0EYjARpmTDmRu2RCBPYaWA)

Pergunto então, na língua escrita e falada:
é correto usar "fácil" como um advérbio?  É aceitável?  É errado?

Comment: Como observação em Portugal usaria-se «facilmente».

Comment: Hei @JorgeB. , `usar-se-ia`. O pt.SO anda a fazer-te mal... :p

Comment: @ANeves realemente ahahah

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Fácil*** já vem reconhecido, e sem qualquer advertência, como advérbio no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/f%C3%A1cil), no [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=f%C3%A1cil)  e no Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003), que trancrevo (desabreviando as abreviaturas):

> **fácil** [...] *advérbio* **7** naturalmente <*discursa fácil e empolga os eleitores*> **8** facilmente, à toa <*esta louça quebra fácil*>

Já na [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/f%C3%A1cil) e no dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001), *fácil* aparece apenas como adjetivo. No entanto já ouvi esse uso adverbial em Portugal, na expressão *isso resolve-se fácil*, como [neste blogue do Sporting](http://grandeartistaegoleador.blogs.sapo.pt/hoje-joga-o-sporting-170818?thread=71234) e [neste do Benfica](http://serbenfiquista.com/forum/index.php?topic=57607.10745;wap2). Este uso será em Portugal mais recente e menos comum que no Brasil, e será melhor evitá-lo em comunicações mais formais.

Note-se que o uso adverbial de adjetivos não é nada de novo no português: nós podemos andar *rápido*; vender *caro* ou *barato*; jogar *limpo* e falar *claro* ou *baixo* ou *alto*; e não *raro* falamos *grosso* também.

Comment: Muito interessante o último parágrafo.  São frases que uso habitualmente mas ainda não tinha percebido estar usando adjetivos como advérbios.

Comment: @Centaurus Eu de *rápido* estava consciente, mas não das outras. Possivelmente porque nunca se diz *falar baixamente*; mas dizemos *falar claramente*, claro. No vender parece-me que se pode subentender *vender (tudo/algo) caro*; afinal *vender* é primariamente um verbo transitivo; e aí *caro/barato* já pode ser adjetivo.

Comment: @Centaurus E ainda fui ao normalmente purista Gramaticalhas, à procura de opinião contrária, e não é que lá nos dizem que [*a cerveja caíu redondo* e *a juiza trabalha pesado*](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI80433,61044-Desce+redondo+ou+desce+redonda+) está muito bem. Mas *redondo* e *pesado* também vêm no dicionários como advérbios.

Comment: Jacinto,  Há mais ou menos 30 anos, na época em que surgiu um comercial de TV, aqui no Brasil, com a frase  "XXX, a cerveja que desce redondo", professores e gramáticos uniram-se em criticar o uso do adjetivo. Lembro bem disso. Passados vários anos, acho que esse uso foi consagrado.  É o que muitos gramáticos descritivistas dizem: o uso popular consagra. Determinados erros de Português, se usados pela maioria do povo, de forma ininterrupta, acabam aceitos como coloquialismo pelo menos. Afinal, quem faz a língua é o povo. Os gramáticos tentam apenas normatizar o seu uso para não virar bagunça.

Comment: @Centaurus E por isso mesmo a norma culta está sempre atrasada em relação à língua viva, os gramáticos "correm atrás". Esse caso de palavras de outras categorias cumprirem função de advérbio é tão comum que poderia muito bem ser absorvida como "regra" das gramáticas normativas – i.e., adjetivo e advérbio são funções, não "condenam" as palavras a se restringirem a uma ou outra categoria. Se é que já não estão absorvendo.